# Creating database table in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create table with procedure `CREATE_TABLE` and then insert the information into the created table with procedure `PRINT_INFO` but I am getting an exception:

> Errors: PROCEDURE PRINT_INFO Line/Col: 4/3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement
> ignored Line/Col: 4/15 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE Line/Col: 5/3 PLS-00103: Encountered
> the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
> return select update while with       <<    continue close current
> delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute
> commit forall merge pipe purge    json_exists json_value json_query
> json_object json_array

And here is my code example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_INFO
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE_T (TABLE_ID, MESSAGE) VALUES (1, 'Hello World!');
END PRINT_INFO;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE
IS
BEGIN

  CREATE TABLE TABLE_T(
    TABLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE VARCHAR2(25), 
    PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_ID)
  );
  
  PRINT_INFO;
  
END CREATE_TABLE;
/

EXEC CREATE_TABLE;
```

Where could be the problem? How can I get rid of an exception?

Comment: @Littlefoot has given you the technical reason for your errors.  I'd go further and suggest that there is no reason to be writing PL/SQL procedures to create tables.  Table creation should be a one-time activity that can/should be done with straight sql.   Is this a class project?  I could swear I've seen this same question in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both procedures have to use dynamic SQL:

- `print_info` because it inserts into a table which - at compilation time - doesn't exist yet
- `create_table` because it runs DDL and - in order to do that - you need to use dynamic SQL

Therefore:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_INFO
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    execute immediate q'[INSERT INTO TABLE_T (TABLE_ID, MESSAGE) VALUES (1, 'Hello World!')]';
  5  END PRINT_INFO;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_T(' ||
  5      'TABLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, ' ||
  6      ' MESSAGE VARCHAR2(25), '    ||
  7      ' PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_ID) '    ||
  8      ')';
  9
 10    PRINT_INFO;
 11  END CREATE_TABLE;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC CREATE_TABLE;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM table_t;

  TABLE_ID MESSAGE
---------- -------------------------
         1 Hello World!

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a string and assign your ddl to that variable then use
`execute immediate your_variable` ;

Comment: no you do not _have_ to declared a string and assign your ddl to it.  You can just as easily "execute immediate 'select my_col from my_table' ; "  That said, I _prefer_ to assign it to a varaible, so that I can also reference it in dbms_output.put_line for debugging.

Comment: I would go a step further than @EdStevens.  Putting the actual statement in a variable allows me to log the actual statement is case of an exception.  But this should NOT be in a procedure anyway.

Comment: @Belayer - _"But this should NOT be in a procedure anyway_".  Correct - for production code.  But I did say "for debugging".  We put lots of stuff in code for debugging that we take out when debugging is complete and were are going to production.

Comment: @EdStevens - Yes. I too. But the point putting the statement into a variable is useful for *more* than debugging.