# It is possible to modify data in loop from table which was created in previous procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm learning to work with PL/SQL procedures. Now I am trying to create table `TABLE_T` in procedure `CREATE_TABLE` then I trying to insert data with procedure `INSERT_DATA`. Inserted data should be modified in procedure `MODIFY_DATA`.

So data after insertion should look like:

```
LINE_ID | LINE_MESSAGE
----------------------
   1    |   'Hello'
   2    |   'Hi'
   3    |   'Ciao'
```

After modification, they should look like:

```
LINE_ID | LINE_MESSAGE
----------------------
   1    |   'Hello world!'
   2    |   'Hi world!'
   3    |   'Ciao world!'
```

But the procedure `MODIFY_DATA` throwing an **exception**, because allegedly the table does not exist:

> Errors: PROCEDURE MODIFY_DATA Line/Col: 4/17 PL/SQL: SQL Statement
> ignored Line/Col: 4/51 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> Line/Col: 6/6 PL/SQL: Statement ignored Line/Col: 6/66 PLS-00364: loop
> index variable 'REC' use is invalid
>
> Errors: PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA Line/Col: 7/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE Line/Col: 8/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored

And this is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MODIFY_DATA
IS
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (SELECT LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE FROM TABLE_T)
    LOOP
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TABLE_T SET LINE_MESSAGE = ''' || REC.LINE_MESSAGE || ' world!'' WHERE LINE_ID = ' || REC.LINE_ID;
    END LOOP;
END MODIFY_DATA;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE_T(LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE) VALUES (1, ''Hello'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE_T(LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE) VALUES (2, ''Hi'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE_T(LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE) VALUES (3, ''Ciao'')';
    MODIFY_DATA;
END INSERT_DATA;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_T ('
    || 'LINE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,'
    || 'LINE_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(33) NOT NULL,'  
    || 'PRIMARY KEY(LINE_ID))';
    INSERT_DATA;
END CREATE_TABLE;
/

EXEC CREATE_TABLE;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @AlexPoole but table is created with immediate command, so it should exist or no ? I am new in PL/SQL, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66408389/266304), `table_t` still doesn't exist when the `modify_data` procedure is created - which is what the error is telling you - so it can't be used in a static cursor.

> but table is created with immediate command, so it should exist or no ?

It isn't created until the `create_table` procedure is executed; which is *after* `modify_data` is created. When you try to create that procedure the static line:

```
FOR REC IN (SELECT LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE FROM TABLE_T)
```

is trying to reference the `table_t` which doesn't yet exist. It doesn't matter that your code implies the execution order - from having `create_table` call `insert_data`, and that calling `modify_data`; which is unusual anyway, it might seem more natural to do this instead:

```
EXEC CREATE_TABLE;
EXEC INSERT_DATA;
EXEC MODIFY_DATA;
```

But either way, the problem is when you *create* `modify_data`, not when you execute.

---

You could use a dynamic cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MODIFY_DATA
IS
    CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
    TYPE REC_TYPE IS RECORD (
      LINE_ID NUMBER,
      LINE_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(33)
    );
    REC REC_TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR 'SELECT LINE_ID, LINE_MESSAGE FROM TABLE_T';
    LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO REC;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TABLE_T SET LINE_MESSAGE = ''' || REC.LINE_MESSAGE || ' world!'' WHERE LINE_ID = ' || REC.LINE_ID;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR;
END MODIFY_DATA;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33119a8c6699525bde803d71c48a499c)

Answer (score -1):

check your code execution sequence:

```
EXEC CREATE_TABLE;
EXEC INSERT_DATA;
EXEC MODIFY_DATA;
```