# ORA-06550: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error, when table is referenced on the same script that creates it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I'm trying to repopulate a table using a created backup table in the same script.
But it returns an error (*ORA-06550: line 14, column 46: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*) when I run (F5) it on Toad.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
SET serveroutput ON

BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE1_BACKUP AS SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE1';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE1';

    BEGIN 
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE1_BACKUP)
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE1 (column1, column2, column3)
            VALUES (rec.column1, rec.column2, rec.column3);
        END LOOP rec;
    END;
                
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE1_BACKUP';

END;
```

Comment: Seems to be a rush on this exact issue in the last few days:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408389/creating-database-table-in-pl-sql-procedure/66408439?noredirect=1#comment117408887_66408439  And I'm pretty sure I've seen it on other forums as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, it won't work. Table doesn't exist at compile time. `INSERT` will also have to be dynamic.